# How to concatenate results when using PIVOT in Teradata Studio

Tags: sql, pivot, teradata

I have a table with one or more rows for each value of the ID column. Now I want to pivot this table and aggregate the resulting values of the value columns by concatenation in SQL.

Below is an example of what I want to achieve using R and tidyverse. Each person can have one or more other persons for a specific relationship type:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  person = c("Tina", "Tina", "Tina", "Rachel", "Rachel", "Rachel"),
  relationship_with = c("George", "Jamal", "Thomas", "Joe", "Taylor", "Bruce"),
  relationship_type = c("friend", "friend", "coworker", "friend", "coworker","coworker")
)
df |> pivot_wider(names_from = relationship_type, 
                  values_from = relationship_with,
                  values_fn = ~paste(., collapse=","))


# A tibble: 2 × 3
  person friend       coworker    
  <chr>  <chr>        <chr>       
1 Tina   George,Jamal Thomas      
2 Rachel Joe          Taylor,Bruce
```

Using SQL in Teradata Studio I would try to do the same thing in this way.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT person, relationship_with, relationship_type
  FROM df
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
PIVOT (
  CONCAT(relationship_with) FOR relationship_type IN (
   'friend',
   'coworker'
)
) AS pivot;
```

Unfortunately, I get a syntax error with the code above. It seems one has to use SQL aggregation functions like AVG, MEAN, MAX, etc. inside PIVOT. CONCAT is not allowed inside PIVOT. How can I still achieve what I want using SQL?

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you would use `xmlagg` , lots of info here about that.  I have no idea if that will work inside your pivot though.

Comment: `xmlagg` also is not supported inside `pivot`. Is there a way to accomplish what I need without a pivot altogether?

Comment: You would use `xmlagg` instead of `pivot`. But `npath` would be better than either of those.

Comment: I tried with code like this 
`with cte as (...)
select person,
xmlagg(relationship_with || ',' order by person)
from  cte
group by person, relationship_type;`
When I run this in Teradata Studio a dialog pops up: "Specify the dispositions of LOB data". After I uncheck "save to file" I am getting an error: "This SQLXML object is not readable" Any idea what could be the cause (and the fix)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it by first using `xmlagg()` and then doing a `pivot()`:

```
-- Preselect your columns here 
with cte as (
 select
 person,
 relationship_with,
 relationship_type
 from df
), 

-- Create another CTE that performs the aggregation using XMLAGG
aggr as (
select 
person, 
relationship_type,
trim( trailing ',' from (
xmlagg(trim(relationship_with) || ',' order by person) 
)) as relationship_with

from  cte 
group by person, relationship_type
)

-- Pivot the aggregated table
-- Using max() here, but this is just because pivot() requires an aggregation function
select
*
from aggr
pivot (max(ZuPartner) FOR Beziehungstyp IN (
  'friend', 'coworker'
)
) pivo;
```